# android get device screen number with programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How to get programmatically screen number for Android devices, want to take them programmatically such as Xiaomi mi 11 ultra has 2 screen , I want to learn and control it programmatically from can be library of Android or operating system library ?

Comment: @AliasCartellano That code won't work on Android since it uses Java AWT which is not fully implemented on Android. The correct way for Android is here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation#using-the-display-manager-to-choose-a-presentation-display

Comment: @ecle if there is another program exist like screen recorder, how to we handle it because they will be increase size of array. How to distinguish real screen or screen recorder display ?